# LEFT JOIN with specific criteria

Tags: sql, ms-access

In VBA-Ado (Access file)

**T1**

```
id   Item    TransactionDate  
-----------------------------
1    TV      31/12/2017
```

**T2**

```
id   Item   U_Price      FromDate
--------------------------
1    TV     12.1$        31/12/2018   
2    TV     15.3$        30/11/2019   
3    TV     11.2$        25/02/2020  
4    TV     21.1$        01/05/2016
```

I need a LEFT JOIN such that the resulting table has 1 record (from T1) with the most relevant **U_Price**, in the example *21.1$* with the highest **FromDate** smaller than the **TransactionDate**

I've tried with no success

```
    SELECT
        Item,
        TransactionDate
    FROM
       T1 p
    LEFT JOIN T2 o ON o.Item = p.Item
   WHERE T2.FromDate>=T1.TransactionDate
```

Comment: *the highest FromDate smaller than the TransactionDate* is `01/05/2016 `, so the result should be `21.1$`.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One method is a correlated subquery:

```
select t1.*,
       (select t2.u_price
        from t2
        where t2.item = t1.item and t2.fromdate <= t1.transactiondate
        order by t2.fromdate desc
        fetch first 1 row only
       ) as u_price
from t1;
```

Not all databases support the standard `fetch` clause.  Your database might use `limit`, `select top` or something different.

In MS Access, you would use:

select t1.*,
(select top 1 t2.u_price
from t2
where t2.item = t1.item and t2.fromdate <= t1.transactiondate
order by t2.fromdate desc
) as u_price
from t1;

Comment: Using VBA-Ado with Access db

Comment: How can I fetch another field from t2?

Comment: @user3387046 . . . That is not the question that you asked, but the idea is either another correlated subquery or to return the id of the row and then join back to the table.  You might want to ask another question, given that this question has been answered.

Answer (score 0):

I'd do this using `APPLY`, rather than a join:

```
SELECT *
FROM T1
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT TOP 1 * 
    FROM T2
    WHERE T2.Item = T1.Item
       AND T2.FromDate < T1.TransactionDate
    ORDER BY T2.FromDate DESC
) T2_0
```

Note: this is Sql Server specific. You didn't tell us what kind of database you have. Other databases may use a `LATERAL JOIN` instead of `APPLY`, and `LIMIT` or `FETCH` constructions instead of `TOP 1`.

If `U_Price` is really the **only** field you need, I might also do this as a correlated derived table (subquery) in the `SELECT` clause.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with `FIRST_VALUE()` window function:

```
SELECT DISTINCT T1.Item, T1.TransactionDate, 
       FIRST_VALUE(T2.U_Price) OVER (PARTITION BY T1.Item ORDER BY T2.FromDate DESC) U_Price
FROM T1 LEFT JOIN T2 
ON T2.Item = T1.Item AND T2.FromDate <= T1.TransactionDate
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=ff54f6c1409033db35e9f8290a4db74f).
Results:

| Item | TransactionDate | U_Price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| TV | 2017-12-31 | 21.1$ |