# subquery fetching 2 columns

Tags: sql, ms-access

In Access database file, I have:

T1

```
id   Item    TransactionDate  
-----------------------------
1    TV      31/12/2017
```

T2

```
id   Item   U_Price      FromDate      Type
--------------------------------------------
1    TV     12.1$        31/12/2018   Smart55
2    TV     15.3$        30/11/2019   Smart55
3    TV     11.2$        25/02/2020   Smart56
4    TV     21.1$        01/05/2016   Smart10
```

I need the resulting table to have 1 row (from T1) with the most relevant `U_Price`, in the example 21.1$ with the highest `FromDate` smaller than the `TransactionDate`

The question has been properly answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66375176/left-join-with-specific-criteria?noredirect=1#comment117345437_66375176) but now I need to fetch `Type` also

Comment: Surely there must be more than 1 record for TV in T1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider:

```
SELECT T1.*, Top1.* FROM T1 INNER JOIN (
      SELECT T2.* FROM T2
      WHERE ID IN (
          SELECT TOP 1 Dupe.ID FROM T2 AS Dupe INNER JOIN T1 
          ON Dupe.Item=T1.Item 
          WHERE Dupe.Item=T2.Item AND Dupe.FromDate<=T1.TransactionDate 
          ORDER BY Dupe.FromDate DESC)) AS Top1 
ON T1.Item = Top1.Item;
```

Comment: How do I use 2 queries in the same ado statement?

Comment: What do you mean by 'ado statement'? Do you mean ADODB recordset? Query1 can be a saved query object then Query2 can be SQL for opening a recordset.

Comment: Indeed ADODB recordset! An example could be very helpful as I have neither used a "saved query"

Comment: You never have saved a query object - queries that are listed in Navigation Pane? I tried nesting Query1 SQL into Query2 and then it all fails. What do you want to do with recordset?

Comment: Indeed ADODB recordset! Thanks. I figured out how to do it

Comment: Figured out how to get all-in-one SQL - was just missing a paren.

Comment: It seems that when  T1   has many records (about over 1000), Query2 takes a long time or even freezes! Any idea why?

Comment: Probably because T2 is associated with itself by Cartesian relationship (no JOIN clause). Did you try @Dy.Lee suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT T1.*, b.U_price, b.type from T1 ,
(SELECT *
FROM t2
WHERE U_price 
    in( Select Top 1 a.U_price
         FROM T1, T2 as a 
         Where t1.item = a.item and  a.fromDate < t1.transactionDate  order by a.fromDate desc)
) as b
```

Comment: It looks that no other field from t1 is available!

Comment: @user3387046, Your question was a little vague. The answer was corrected.